# How to link from an ASP.Net gridview column field to an .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm using an asp.net gridview to display a list of data from an mdb file. There are 5 columns displayed, with approximately 240 rows of data. Each row displays "first name", last name", "title", "genre", "issue", and "id".

Each "title" entry has corresponding .aspx page. There are approximately 180 actual .aspx pages that corresponds to the "title" entries in the grid.
An example of this relationship looks like: title = "Once upon a time in a long story"; and the aspx page might be /alongstory.aspx.

What I want to accomplish: Allow users to click the title field on the grid and open corresponding .aspx page.

What I've done so far: created a aspLabel on the "title" field - Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>'; and added C# code for label load event:

```
    aspLabel l = sender as aspLabel;
    l.ClientsideEvents.Click = String.Format("function(s,e) {{window.location = \"{0}"; }}, GetPageUrl(l));
```

And the GetPageUrl:

```
     Private string GetPageUrl(aspLabel l)
     {GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer c = l.NamingContainer as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer:
    var value = (string)DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Title"); 
    string result;
    switch (value) {
         case "in the mirror":
            result = "AnotherTitlePage.aspx";
            break;
        case "When your Eyes":
            result = "AnotherTitlePage2.aspx";
            break;
        case "Her Delivery":
            result = "ATitlePage1.aspx";
            break;
        case "You Never Know What You Might See":
            result = "TitlePage3.aspx";
            break;              
        default:
            result = "TitlePageDoesNotHavesameNameAsDBEntry.aspx";
            break;
    }
    return Page.ResolveUrl(result);
}
```

While this works, it requires all titles be hard coded into corresponding select statement along with the corrosponding url, which equates to 240 cases! Further, the only field which uniquely identifies each row is the "id" value, which in an integer - I've had a problem trying to set up a case select for int and return the proper url (casting error is the problem).

What I hope to accomplish:
Find the most efficient way to open the corrosponding url for the click on the "title" field of the grid view without hard coding both the field name from the grid column and the url into the case select.

So, given the information above, would a case select be the best approach for this requirement? 
Any examples or suggestions of better approaches would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making 180 actual .aspx pages, you must have to use concept of routing introduced in c# 4.0 and above.

here you can generate N number of pages dynamically and only one page will be work as template.

please refer below link for more details

[URL Routing in asp.net as example www.jobdoor.in](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0)